# diff folders recursively vs. multithreading

Tags: multithreading, performance, shell, unix, diff

I need to compare two directory structures with around one billion files each (directory deepness up to 20 levels)

I found usual `diff -r /location/one /location/two` slow.

Is there any implementation of multithreading diff? Or is it doable via combining `shell` and `diff` together? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your disk is gonna be the bottleneck.

Unless you are working on tmpfs, you will probably only loose speed. That said:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 |
    xargs -0P4 -n1 -iDIRNAME diff -EwburqN "DIRNAME/" "/tmp/othertree/DIRNAME/"
```

should do a pretty decent job of comparing trees (in this case `.` to `/tmp/othertree`).

It has a flaw right now, in that it won't detect toplevel directories in `otherthree` that don't exist in `.`. *I leave that as an exercise for the reader - though you could easily repeat the comparison in reverse*

The argument `-P4` to xargs specifies that you want at most 4 concurrent processes.

Also have look at **[the `xjobs` utitlity](http://www.maier-komor.de/xjobs.html)** which does a better job at separating the output. I think with GNU xargs (like shown) you cannot drop the `-q` option because it will intermix the diffs (?).

Comment: great, although that little issue it's very nice solution, thanks!

Comment: might also be a good job for [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

Comment: @hometoast or make -j<N> or xjobs or ... UNIX 1-tool-1-job philosophy at work :)